# Accessing local store in a multi device hybrid app

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Is there a standard API to access the local store in a multi-device hybrid app? I want to store app-specific user settings.

In Android, I have to use SharedPreferences and in Windows I have to use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings. What do I use in a MDHA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cordova you use openDatabase:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html